# Send android app device token to WordPress web from a TWA

Tags: php, android, wordpress, token, twa

I'm building a TWA which opens a **WordPress** site and shows some data addressed to a few numbers of users. Each user must see specific information according to his/her place in a chain of orders and, thus, receive different notifications.

Now, on certain WP events (creating a custom post type post, for instance), PHP Performs an HTTP request with **wp_remote_post** to send notifications throughout **Firebase** to **ALL** the devices carrying the app, which is less than ideal.

So, I suppose the way to narrow down the sending of notifications is to get the token of each app (TWA), store in **WordPress** in the **wp_usermeta** table (so it is linked to each different user) and use it to send tailored notifications according to the events going on in the site.

Well, that's my question:

**Is there any way to send this tokens securely from the TWA to WordPress** as easy and straightforward as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the best way to implement push notifications in a Trusted Web Activity is to implement [web push notifications in the Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications) and then [enable Notification Delegation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/master/demos/twa-notification-delegation) in the Trusted Web Activity.

In the cases where this is not the best solution, [you can use custom HTTP headers](https://developers.google.com/web/android/custom-tabs/headers) to send information from the Android app to the Trusted Web Activity (assuming [query strings](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/query-parameters) are not desirable due to security).